# How can I develop Eclipse search Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to develop a plug in view which will automatically call the search plug-in in Eclipse and display all the positions where a particular function was called in a package.

Help me! How should i go about it? Thanks

Comment: I am not able to get the package to be searched.I have been using IPackageFragment to specify package(unable to do thatproperly) and then create JavaSearchScope(which is failing due to that). I am unable to do that . Help !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more good tutorial for plugin developement http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

And related to implementation of any class, its your job to do that. You can ask help for how to go about that, not rather getting ready for you.

Comment: Yeah i want to implement the class and have started it by creating a searchengine class,then implementing IJavaElemnt interface . I am struck there . Next i will be creating Javasearchscope but i should get the elements of type IJavaElement for method search.

How can i do that?

Comment: @Nishan: I would start by looking at the source-code for some other plugin (or whatever) that customizes Java search.

Comment: @Nishan - and you could also try searching the relevant Eclipse newsgroups.

Comment: @Stephen C -any links to the source code of plugin that customizes search

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading [Your First Plug-in: Developing the Eclipse "Hello World" plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html).

Comment: Yeah . I have done that.Now i am able to take package name as input from user from text box. I want to pass that package name to my search method where i will have the logic to invoke the search API and return back the result ( the positions of method call ) and display in message box.

how should i implement that class ?