# Extending Eclipse Java Search

Tags: java, eclipse, search, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm developing an eclipse plugin where a user can search a java code given some text query, similar to the usual java search dialog in eclipse.

[image: Java Search Image]

I'm using the following code to search for a text provided by user

```
SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern("<search_string>",
            IJavaSearchConstants.TYPE, IJavaSearchConstants.PARAMETER_DECLARATION_TYPE_REFERENCE,
            SearchPattern.R_EXACT_MATCH);

    // step 2: Create search scope
    // IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(packages);
    IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();

    // step3: define a result collector
    SearchRequestor requestor = new SearchRequestor()
    {
        public void acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch match) 
        {
            System.out.println(match.getElement());
        }
    };

    // step4: start searching
    SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
    try {
        searchEngine.search(pattern, new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine
                        .getDefaultSearchParticipant() }, scope, requestor,
                        null);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also I'm able to pass the query string from Search Dialogue to a class implementing ISearchPage.[image: Search Dialog page Image]

```
    public class QuerySearchPage extends DialogPage implements ISearchPage 
{
    ...
    public boolean performAction() 
    {
        System.out.println(txtQuery.getText());

        search();//search using the SearchEngine
        SearchOperation so = new SearchOperation(iFileSet);
        IRunnableWithProgress query = so;
        try 
        {
            container.getRunnableContext().run(true, true, query);
        } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally I got stuck at the point where I need to pass the search result to ISearchResultView. Basically, I have two questions:

1. Matched results are of type Object. How to pass these results to ISearchResultView which takes IFile as input?
2. How to get results in the below format?

[image: Search Result View Image]

I have already gone through the following links:

- http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fsearch_page.htm
- http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/plugin_dev/
- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5.2/org.eclipse/search/3.5.1/org/eclipse/search/ui/ISearchResult.java?av=f
- http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2015/07/a-custom-search-provider.html
- http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Bals10b-EclipsePlugins.pdf
- [How can I develop Eclipse search Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152430/how-can-i-develop-eclipse-search-plugin)
- http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FISearchResult.html
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_a_search_operation%3F

Any help is highly welcomed.

Comment: `ISearchResultView` is deprecated, `ISearchResultPage` declared using the `org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages` is the recommended method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would implement a `ISearchResultPage` that is capable of displaying the search result. In its `createControl()` method you need to create a viewer that knows how to present the matches.

A commonly used abstract implementation of `ISearchResultPage` is `AbstractTextSearchViewPage`. This class uses a `TableViewer` or a `TreeViewer` to present the machtes, depending on whether they are hierarchical or not. In case you use the latter, implement its `configureTreeViewer()` and/or `configureTableViewer()` methods so that the viewers are equipped with label providers and content providers that know the specific type that represents a match, i.e. what you referred to as the 'Matched results of type Object'.

The `AbstractTextSearchViewPage` constructor must be told which kinds of layouts it supports: `FLAG_LAYOUT_FLAT` and/or `FLAG_LAYOUT_TREE`. The actual representation can be changed with `setLayout()`.

To start with you could restrict the search view page to a *flat* layout and implement its `configureTableViewer()` like this:

```java
viewer.setLabelProvider( new MyLabelProvider() );
viewer.setContentProvider( new MyContentProvider() );
```

The input for the content provider is your `ISearchResult` implementation. Hence the `MyContentProvider` could obtain the elements to be shown from the search result.

```java
@Override
public void inputChanged( Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput ) {
  searchResult = ( MySearchResult )newInput;
}

@Override
public Object[] getElements( Object inputElement ) {
  return searchResult.getElements();
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have created a class FileSearchResultContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider, IStructuredContentProvider and also modified SearchResultPage to extend AbstractTextSearchViewPage, but how should I implement configureTreeViewer method and other methods that need to overridden in class FileSearchResultContentProvider.

Comment: I did whatever changes mentioned, But still not able to follow what you are suggesting. Can you please review my code here - https://github.com/payamrastogi/searchprovider

Comment: Your `SearchResultPage` overrides `createControl()`. If you look into the super class you'll probably notice that this is not what you want.

Comment: I have removed the setLayout statement (repository updated), still no results.

Comment: You need to carefully look into the methods that you override in `SearchResultPage` and decide whether you actually need to override a method. As I noted above, `createControl()` is not meant to be overridden when extending `AbstractTextSearchViewPage `.